# how to load json file output(subprocess) into a variable in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, subprocess

have a python code that generates random data everytime . i run it using subprocess.

first.py

code :

```
for _ in range(50):
sms =  {

    "name": fake.name(),
    "email": fake.email() 
      }


with open('sfirst.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(sms, outfile)
```

subprocess:

```
  subprocess.call(["python","first.py")
```

output :

```
    {

    "name": "elmaro",
    "email": "elmaro@gmail.com" 
      }
```

how to store every output generated by values in a dictionaries or any other useful format in 1,2,3,4,...50 . so that i can use them later.

example:

```
 here we are looping 50 times so 
 {
 "name1": elmaro,
  "email1": elamro@gmail.com,
 "name2": spetus,
  "email2": spetus@gmail.com
    ........
  ........
   }
  upto 50 times should be stored and when i call 

  data[email45] it should return the value stored
```

Comment: I recommend rewriting `first.py` as a module that contains a function you can call, said function returning a dictionary rather than writing a JSON-encoded object to a file.

Comment: can you elaborate more about that. i am new

Comment: Don't use `subprocess` to run another Python program if you can simply use the code directly from the first program.

Comment: i have to use the subprocess and first.py will generate one random data if we run once. if i loop the subprocess for 50 times it only stores the last updated output. what i need is to append all the output data in here 50 random data into dict so that i can use them further

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["python","first.py"])
```

out will contain the output generated by the command

```
output_dict = dict()
output_dict['you need code to compute this'] = out['name']
output_dict['you need code to compute this as well'] = out['email']
```

Let me know if you don't figure it out

```
output_dict = dict()

for loop in range(50):
    out = check_output(["python","first.py"])
    emailKey = str(loop) + 'email'
    nameKey = str(loop) + 'name'
    output_dict[nameKey] = out['name']
    output_dict[emailKey] = out['email']
```

Comment: `out will contain the output generated by the command`. if we run it in loop will it append ??

Comment: so you update the dict in the loop and declare it outside the loop so that it doesn't get re initialized

Comment: first.py will generate one random data if we run once.  if i loop the subprocess for 50 times it only stores the last updated output. what i need is to append all the output data in here 50 random data into dict so that i can use them further

Comment: updated the response, I hope the pseudo code makes sense now

Comment: sure will check and let u knw

Comment: `output_dict['you need code to compute this'] = out['name']`   getting this TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str